# Getting src from image, without http, from within iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Situation is as following:

Main page with image and iFrame.

In this iFrame, I want to get the src of the image. Got some code for it, but it will spit out a full link, including the http:// part. I only want the local piece.

Code used:

```
<p id="infoX">test</p>

<script>
var x = parent.document.getElementById("image");

document.getElementById("infoX").innerHTML = x.src;

</script>';
```

Result is: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/images/image.jpg.

Desired result: images/image.jpg.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
var split_array = x.src.split("/")
var answer = split_array[split_array.length-2]+'/'+ split_array[split_array.length-1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This would work in this example. But if I would have files in a folder like images/layout/mainLayout/image.jpg, your sollution wouldn't work anymore. Same goes for when I am going to acces a dir outside of my root.

Comment: you need to think about the structure your URL take or be more specific, Maybe concatenating split_array[2] to split_array[length] will work as far as I can understand.